# Using a Python dictionary to simulate switch statement with default case

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a valid Python syntax for the following idea:

```py
d = {_: 'value for any other key', 'x': 'value only for x key'}
value = d[key]
```

which should assign `'value only for x key'` value ONLY when `key='x'`?

I have the following structure in my code, but I want to replace it with something that looks like the statements above.

```py
if key == 'x':
  value = 'value only for x key'
else:
  value = 'value for any other key'
```

Comment: The way you do a default value with a dict lookup is `d.get(key, 'value for any other key')`.  You could write that as `d.get(key, d['_'])` if you really wanted the default value stored in the dict itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a `defaultdict` from the `collections` module, as it avoids the need to check for membership in the dictionary using `if/else` or `try/except`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: 'value for any other key', {'x': 'value only for x key'})

item = 'x'
value = d[item]
print(value) # Prints 'value only for x key'

item = 'y'
value = d[item]
print(value) # Prints 'value for any other key'
```

Comment: just note this *automatically creates a key-value pair* which is probably undesirable. and you can just use `.get`.

Comment: Thanks!! this worked like a charm and it's the style I wanted, the actual code is much more convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

Python has `match` statement which is the equivalent to the `C`'s `switch` statement since version `3.10`, but your method may be used too:

```
dictionary = {
    'a': my_a_value,
    'b': my_b_value,
    '_': my_default_value
}
try:
    x = dictionary[input()]
except KeyError:
    x = dictionary['_']
```

Comment: "Python has match statement which is the equivalent to the C's switch " **no it absolutely is not equivalent**.  It is superficially similar, and you can think of `switch` as a *very limited* version of `match`, but `match` uses structural pattern matching

Comment: Could you provide a link with a description of the additional features of match? Thanks 

Comment: A good place to start is the PEP that proposed it: https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#overview Essentially, the thing to understand is that the *structural pattern matching* is key feature, so what you really want to compare it to is functional programing constructs like "pattern matching" in Haskell instead of switch in C. It *matches* on the structure of a pattern and deconstructs that match. A switch merely checks for equality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary's get function to customize the return value:

```
d = {
    'x' : 'value only for x key', 
    'y' : 'value only for y key',
    '_' : 'value for any other key'
}

key = input("Enter the key")

value = d.get(key, d['_'])

print("Value is ", value)
```

Comment: probably `d.get(key, "value for any other key")` makes more sense, why have `"_"` in the dict? I think the OP was using that as a pretend syntax to indicate a behavior that he hoped dict's have

Comment: Lol, you are right. It's just a random way to imitate default for the switch implementation.